# Accessing Cloud Run Service through existing VPC with VPN Tunnel from corp network

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-vpc

We currently have a VPC named `ABC` which contains various instances which we can reach through a dedicated VPN tunnel from our corporate network and everything there has been working fine for well over a year.
We are now wanting to run some containers within Cloud Run.  I have deployed our container and by switching the `Ingress Control` to `All` I am able to reach the URL and hit the endpoint that our container is serving up.  We don't want our container to be publicly accessible so we want to restrict access to the corporate network.  I have created a VPC connector `ABC-Conn` to connect to `ABC` with a Subnet or 10.8.0.0/28 (default).  What I cannot figure out is how to from my desktop on how to reach the service being served up by Cloud Run.  Whenever I try to hit the URL I get a 403 which I am suspecting that means I am not going through our corp VPN tunnel but rather straight out to the internet to hit the service.  I am assuming its something to do with the routing and I do see a route for 10.8.0.0/28 with a priority of 0 but obviously that isn't enough

Comment: What are your corp network routing configuration? When you hit the Cloud Run URL you don't have to go to the internet, but be routed through the VPN. It's not native, you have to perform router update to add that custom internal route.

Comment: For the VPC, we have our "corporate" routes defined where the destination ip ranges (10.1.X.X) with a priority of 1000 that has a next hop to a VPN Tunnel to our corporate network.

Comment: Yes but the route target is not 10.X it's a public IP by default. So you have to route the domain of Cloud Run through the VPN. More here https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the VPC Connector is only for egress traffic and is used to enable de Cloud Run to consume resources on the VPC by the private IP. Is not necessary in your use case.

In your scenario, you want to consume in a private way the Cloud Run you have two options:

1. The first solution is to set up an Internal Load Balancer in front of the Cloud Run, follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal-serverless):
2. Set up [Private Google Access with your onPrem networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/private-connectivity#on-premises_network_example). For this option, if the VPN is in a different project than the Cloud Run you need to implement a [VPC Service Control](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls)

I recommend option 2 because is a secure way and is valid for other GCP resources in the future.

Comment: I don't have the level of permissions on the VPC service control but we did decide on the load balancer approach to gain access.  Thanks!